# Identifying possible data leakage

Tags: xgboost, class-imbalance, data-leakage

I am building a binary classification model for imbalanced dataset using XGBoost. I tuned the hyperparameters for four different models based on 2 training datasets and 2 optimization metrics.

1. Class Imbalanced dataset; Optimize for Accuracy
2. Class Imbalanced dataset; Optimize for F1
3. Class balanced dataset; Optimize for Accuracy
4. Class balanced dataset; Optimize for F1
   Each dataset has 500k Samples

Each of the hyperparameter searches was performed based on 10-folds CV schema. After fitting the models with the best found hyperparameters, each model was evaluated against the same test dataset. I made sure that each training dataset is indeed independent from the test dataset.
I also ensured to remove all data just prior to the event of interest, and that the model contains only features that are available to the model at the time of prediction.

I used the following correlation methods to verify that none of the independent features are correlated with the target (dependent variable)

- Pearson correlation (For numerical features)
- spearman correlation (For numerical features)
- Cramér's V correlation (For categorical features)
- theils u (For categorical features)
- correlation ratio (For numerical and categorical features)

While some correlation (>0.9) was found between a few of the independent features, no such correlation was found between any of the independent features and the dependent feature. For the 1st round of model building none of the independent features were removed.

Despite all of this, I was very surprised to find that the model performance on the training and test datasets (for all 4 models) is ‘too good to be true’ on the tuned model.

```
******************** Trn Results ********************
*** Classification_report:
          precision    recall  f1-score   support

     0.0      0.959     0.999     0.978    250000
     1.0      0.999     0.957     0.977    250000

accuracy                          0.978    500000
macro avg      0.979     0.978     0.978    500000
weighted avg      0.979     0.978     0.978    500000

*** accuracy_score: 0.978
*** balanced_accuracy_score: 0.978
*** roc_auc_score: 0.978
*** confusion matrix

    TP FP    239242 327
    FN TN    10758 249673
         
*******************************************************


******************** Test Results ********************
*** Classification_report:
          precision    recall  f1-score   support

     0.0      0.992     0.985     0.989   2275993
     1.0      0.860     0.917     0.888    224007

accuracy                          0.979   2500000
macro avg      0.926     0.951     0.938   2500000
weighted avg      0.980     0.979     0.980   2500000

*** accuracy_score: 0.979
*** balanced_accuracy_score: 0.951
*** roc_auc_score: 0.951
*** confusion matrix

TP FP    205459 33320
FN TN    18548 2242673
*******************************************************
```

To check if there is no simple independent features that are directly correlated with the depended feature, I fitted a model with downgraded quality (small max_depth and n_estimators parameters). In this case the model performance for class 1 (rare class) indeed degraded both for the train and test dataset. Which made me believe that the ‘complex’ model is indeed capturing the correct dynamic.

```
******************** Trn Results ********************
*** Classification_report:
          precision    recall  f1-score   support

     0.0      0.819     0.844     0.831    250000
     1.0      0.839     0.813     0.826    250000

accuracy                          0.829    500000
macro avg      0.829     0.829     0.829    500000
weighted avg      0.829     0.829     0.829    500000

*** accuracy_score: 0.829
*** balanced_accuracy_score: 0.829
*** roc_auc_score: 0.829
*** confusion matrix

TP FP    203354 39035
FN TN    46646 210965
         
*******************************************************


******************** Test Results ********************
*** Classification_report:
          precision    recall  f1-score   support

     0.0      0.979     0.845     0.907   2275993
     1.0      0.340     0.812     0.480    224007

accuracy                          0.842   2500000
macro avg      0.659     0.829     0.693   2500000
weighted avg      0.921     0.842     0.869   2500000

*** accuracy_score: 0.842
*** balanced_accuracy_score: 0.829
*** roc_auc_score: 0.829
*** confusion matrix

TP FP    181928 352543
FN TN    42079 1923450
         
*******************************************************
```

Am I correct to assume that there is some type of data leakage here? How can I identify it?

Comment: Did you perform any standardization/normalization, or imputation of the entire data set prior to your k-fold cross-validation and hyperparameter tuning?

Comment: Yes I did. However, I made sure to include both the standardization and data imputation in a pipeline so they will be fitted to the training folds and applied (transformed) on the test folds.

Comment: Okay, it sounds like we can eliminate the possibility of data leakage from preprocessing steps then